# How can I know which drop down has current focus

Tags: gwt, combobox, smartgwt

In Smart gwt I have multiple drop downs in a screen. I have to clear any selected drop down. How can I know which drop down has current focus?

Comment: if (Field1.getCanFocus()) {
Field1.clearValue();
    }
if (Field2.getCanFocus())
Field2.clearValue();
if (Field3.getCanFocus())
field3.clearValue();

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to add an FocusHandler which is triggered when a dropdow Receives Focus. In the handler, you do the required work.

Here is an example:

```
SelectItem dropdownItem = new SelectItem();
dropdownItem.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler( {
    void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
        SelectItem dropdownItem = (SelectItem) event.getSource();
        dropdownItem.setValueMap(new String[0]);
    }
});
```

If you are not using a SelectItem, don't worry, all Dropdowns in SmartGWt has the **addFocusHandler** method.